# Problem: horizontal scrollbar appears when I add an image to a column using bootstrap 4 grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am super new to coding and web development and I am not sure how to solve my issue:

I am trying to add an image to the column that I created using bootstrap 4 grid system. However, as soon as I add the image, a horizontal scrollbar appears on the screen and I'm not sure why.

Here is a screenshot of what happens: https://gyazo.com/c383ecb9180181349363e0636047867c

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585600270404-543d0eac85e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3042&q=80">
    </div>
</div>
```

My second issue is that although the horizontal scrollbar gets removed when I use the "img-fluid" class for my image, however when I change the container to container-fluid so that it covers the entire width of the screen and then use the class "px-0" for my container to remove the extra padding, I once again get horizontal scrollbars appearing on my screen.

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585600270404-543d0eac85e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3042&q=80">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is due to no restriction on 'width' being applied to the image.
The image is very big and hence, it is causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear.

**Bootstrap provides a class called 'img-fluid' to resolve this common issue.**

The horizontal scroll bar can be avoided by specifying the image class of 'img-fluid', as shown below.

The second problem with the use of container-fluid px-0 can be fixed by specifying the px-lg-5 class instead of px-0.
(px-lg-5 works well for wide sections / outer-most divs)

**Working example with 'img-fluid' and container-fluid px-lg-5 classes:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Bootstrap - responsive image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-lg-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
              <img class="img-fluid" 
                   src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585600270404-543d0eac85e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3042&q=80">
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Comment: That does fix the problem but I also have faced another issue: when I change the container class to "container-fluid" so that it covers the entire width of the screen and also use px-0 to remove the padding once again I get the horizontal scrollbar appearing.

Comment: container-fluid will make the container occupy full width of the screen. This class can be set to the outer most div. Setting it on inner elements may cause undesirable effects. More information on container-fluid can be found at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: can you review my post again, please? I updated it with my code. I have set the container-fluid to the outermost div but I still face the same issue.

Comment: I updated the answer with 'container-fluid px-lg-5' class for the outer div. Can you verify if the issue is resolved now?

Comment: I wanted the picture to be stuck to the left of the screen. Additionally, could you possibly elaborate why px-0 didn't work?

Comment: The effective style applied to each class can be studied in the browser console by inspecting the web element. (right-click --> Inspect). The inspection of px-0 class can show the width that it had applied to the element. Also, the alignment of elements can be controlled using CSS attributes.  More information on CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Either you can set overflow : hidden to the second column container if you want your page to not scroll, or you can set height and width of the image to avoid scrolling and to make the whole image visible.

```
 <div class="col-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
 </div>
 <div class="col-6" style="overflow: hidden">
   <img height="100px" width="100px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585600270404-543d0eac85e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3042&q=80" />
 </div>
```

Learn more about overflow property at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp and image attributes at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

To solve your second problem, just add the `margin:0` to the `<div class="row">`